# Let D be the midpoint of BC in triangle ABC. Let E be the midpoint AD, F be the intersection of line BE with side AC. Find $\frac{AF}{FC}$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio

> Let D be the midpoint of side BC in triangle ABC. Let E be the midpoint of line AD and let F be the intersection of line BE with side AC. Find $\frac{AF}{FC}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem)  for triangle $ADC$ and line $F-E-B$:
$$\frac{AF}{FC}\cdot\frac{CB}{BD}\cdot\frac{DE}{EA}=1$$
$$\frac{AF}{FC}\cdot\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1}=1$$
$$\frac{AF}{FC}=\frac12$$